# Show that $z^2-iz+2$ is continuous at $z_0=1-i$ by using $(\epsilon,\delta)$

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Show that  $f(z)=z^2-iz+2$ is continuous at $z_0=1-i$ by using $(\epsilon,\delta)$

My Attempt: for given $\delta$,if ||(x,y)-(1,-1)||<$\delta$, we have to showed correctly :|x-y|<$\delta$  and |y+1|<$\delta$

Now |f(x,y)-f(1,-1)|=$|x^2-y^2+2ixy-ix-y+2+3i-3|$ i cant process ding further
can any one help me

Comment: Why do you have to show $|x-y|< \delta$ and $|y+1|<\delta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0$ such that if $0<|z-(1-i)|<\delta$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
|f(z)-f(1-i)| &=& |f(z)-(1-3i)|\\
 &=& 
|z^2-iz+2-\Big((1-i)^2-i(1-i)+2\Big)|\\
 &=& 
|(z^2-(1-i)^2)-iz+i(1-i)|\\
 &=& 
|\Big(z-(1-i)\Big)\Big(z+(1-i)\Big)-i\Big(z-(1-i)\Big)|\\
 &=& 
|\Big(z-(1-i)\Big)\Big((z-(1-i))-i\Big)|\\
 &\leq& 
\delta(\delta+1)\\
 &=& 
\varepsilon
\end{eqnarray}
because $|z-(1-i)-i|=|(z-(1-i))-i|\leq|z-(1-i)|+|i|\leq\delta+1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: start with $|f(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon$
$$|z^2-iz+2-(1-i)^2+i(1-i)-2|<\epsilon\\
|z^2-(1-i)^2-i(z-(1-i))|<\epsilon\\
|(x+iy-(1-i))(x+iy+(1-i))-i(x+iy-(1-i))<\epsilon|$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
\begin{array}
f|f(z)-f(z_0)|&=&|z^2-iz+2-(z_0^2-iz_0+2)|\\
&=&|z^2-z_0^2-i(z-z_0)|\\
&=&|z-z_0|(z+z_0-i)\\
&\leq&|z-z_0|(|z|+3)
\end{array}
Can you see something closer to the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote $\tilde z = 1-i$ and take $y = \tilde z + \Delta $, a neighbour point of $~\tilde z$. Then,
$$ \begin{array}[rcl] ~f(y) - f(\tilde z) &=& f(\tilde z+ \Delta) - f(\tilde z)  \\ &=& (\tilde z+\Delta)^2 - i(\tilde z+\Delta) +2 - f(\tilde z) 
\\ &=&  \underbrace{\tilde z^2 - i \tilde z +2}_{f(\tilde z)} +2(\tilde z -i)\Delta + \Delta^2 - f(\tilde z) \\
&=& (2\tilde z -2i + \Delta)\Delta. 
 \end{array} $$
Hence, 
$$ |f(y) - f(\tilde z)| = |2\tilde z -2i+\Delta| |\Delta| \leq (|2\tilde z -2i|+|\Delta|)|\Delta| ,  $$
Hence given $\varepsilon>0 $, if you choose $\delta <1 $ and $\delta< \frac{\varepsilon}{|2\tilde z -2i|}  $ then you have

$$ |f(\tilde{z}) - f(y)|< \varepsilon ~\, \text{if}~\, |y-\tilde z| = |\Delta| <\delta,$$ which proves the statement.